# WPF App scales differently on XP vs Win7 both at 96 DPI

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, scaling

I have an App I designed under Windows 7. The screen was set at 96 DPI. When deploying to a WinXp computer which is also set to 96 dpi the screen looks different. There is extra space left at the left and bottom. Below are the two screen shots. I'm wondering if I need to wrap the display in some UI tool and change some properties to make this look consistent. I tried adding UseLayoutRounding="true" but it didn't appear to do much.

## How it should look (Win7)

[image]

## How it looks under XP

[image]

Comment: It looks like the fonts are different. You can change it to use a font available by default on both target systems, or use a font that is install-able on both, or design two interfaces, one for each font and detect the system at run-time.

Comment: Windows XP doesn't have the Segoe UI font. It uses the Tahoma font. However, WPF generally isn't "absolutely" position like WinForms, it's all relative layout. I'm surprised you are having this problem.

Comment: I guess that brings up a good question. Are you using absolute sizing/positioning for those Delay labels and textboxes/spinners?

Comment: I'm using the default font so that explains the different look to the fonts and possibly the spacing. I wanted to keep the Min window height and width so that the user doesn't make the window  too small for the content. If the font differences shave off enough pixels I guess the window in XP will "shrink" leaving the extra space and causing the borders. The Delay/Width UserControl is a StackPanel inside a GroupBox *BUT* I did have an absolute Width set on the labels via a style. I guess I'll look into either changing to Tahoma or seeing if I can install Segoe on XP.

Comment: @Tim promote your response to an answer, really all three responses were very helpful, the differing fonts cause slight layout differences but it was the scattered fixed sizes that prevented WPF from having complete control.

Comment: @Tod ok, i moved it over to being an answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using fixed sizes in the dialog rather than letting the WPF layout engine handle it with grids and whatnot. For instance, looking at the Delay label, I'm guessing they are fixed size and when the different font is used on XP, the label doesn't grow like it should in a normal WPF app.